# No Response From Localhost Database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm not a professional coder. I'm just trying to make my own website. I did the following steps below, but it didn't work.

**1-** I created categories for the blog at localhost database.

http://i.hizliresim.com/3jqE3M.jpg

**2-** I created database.php as below.

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 

mysql_select_db("mycms"); 

?>
```

**3-** I added the following codes to home.html

```
<?php 
include("includes/database.php"); 

$get_cats = "select * from `categories`"; 

$run_categories = mysql_query($get_cats); 

while ($cats_row=mysql_fetch_array($run_cats)) { 

$cat_id=$cats_row['cat_id']; 
$cat_title=$cats_row['cat_title']; 

echo "<li><a href='home.html?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></li>"; 

} 

?>
```

BUT I can't see categories from http://localhost/MyCMS/home.html

It didn't work. What is the problem ? How can I solve this problem. Please help me :(

Comment: What "didn't work" about it?

Comment: php code on a html page @RowlandShaw. ;)

Comment: @Jai you're assuming that his server isn't set to parse .html files as php (or there's any URL rewriting)

Comment: Yep! As the i can see the question. seems like it @RowlandShaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First PHP code is only executed if the extension of the filename is `.php` so change `home.html` to `home.php`.

Second you have a small error in your code as well.

```
<?php 
include("includes/database.php"); 

$get_cats = "select * from `categories`"; 

$run_categories = mysql_query($get_cats); 

//while ($cats_row=mysql_fetch_array($run_cats)) { 

// The parameter to mysql_fetch_array should be 
// the result of a call to mysql_query()
while ($cats_row=mysql_fetch_array($run_categories )) { 

    $cat_id=$cats_row['cat_id']; 
    $cat_title=$cats_row['cat_title']; 

    echo "<li><a href='home.html?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></li>"; 
} 
?>
```

Also

> Please dont use the `mysql_` database extensions, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
>   Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
>   [and here is some help to decide which to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Change `home.html` into `home.php` as html page with `.html` extension can't execute PHP code. One more thing, `mysql_*` in future will deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `pdo` instead. In while loop, must be sure to pass `$run_categories` instead of `$get_cats` like following code :

```
// this variable only store string, not the query itself
$get_cats = "select * from `categories`";
$run_categories = mysql_query($get_cats); 

while ($cats_row=mysql_fetch_array($run_categories)) {...}
```

**Recommended use either one of below version :**

**1) Mysqli Version**

```
<?php 
// database connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con, "mycms");

$get_cats = "select * from `categories`";
$run_categories = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats); 

while ($cats_row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_categories )) { 

 $cat_id=$cats_row['cat_id']; 
 $cat_title=$cats_row['cat_title'];
 echo "<li><a href='home.html?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></li>";

} 
?>
```

**2) PDO version**

```
<?php 
// database connection
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mycms;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$get_cats = "select * from `categories`";
$run_categories = $con->query($get_cats); 

while ($cats_row = $run_categories->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

 $cat_id=$cats_row['cat_id']; 
 $cat_title=$cats_row['cat_title'];
 echo "<li><a href='home.html?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></li>";

} 
?>
```

Comment: See the answer with `mysqli` and `pdo` version.